# How to store other NSManagedObjects as property of a NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am new to iOS programming and I'm doing up a simple function of an iOS application. Currently, I've created an entity called Players, and I'd like the entity to have a property, in which it stores other NSManagedObject like an array.

This is because I want a player to be able to have friends in the game and this is the way I've thought of; I could just access a player's friend's list via

```
[playername friendList]
```

May I know if this is the way to do so? Because for an entity's attribute type, I couldn't use NSMutableArray or NSArray as its type. If it is, may I know how I can store it? If not, is there a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of relationships in the Core Data model. Add a relationship between the two entities (and an inverse) and add the managed objects to that relationship.

See [this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-CJBDBHCB) of the Core Data guide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a relationship between the models, which are represented with NSSet (or NSOrderedSet, by checking "ordered", if the order is important.)

Ordered Sets are similar to arrays, except all the objects are distinct (no duplicates).